# unowned self in Swift lazy public var initialization emits compiler error, but not with private var initialization

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, protocols

why does the following compile without error:

```
public class MyContainingViewModel {

    public var myViewModel: MyViewModel? {
        return privateMyViewModel
    }

    lazy private var privateMyStatusViewModel: MyViewModel? = { [unowned self] in
        ...
    }
```

but the following results in an error:

```
public class MyContainingProtocol {
    public var quotedStatusViewModel: T1StatusViewModel? = { [unowned self] in
```

error details:

```
 MyViewModel.swift: 'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol
 types, not '(MyContainingViewModel) -> () -> MyContainingViewModel'
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `quotedStatusViewModel` is an instance variable and `self` does not yet exist so you can't use it in your block.  It compiles okay in the first instance because it is `lazy` which means that `self` will be around when this is actually called.